# vertex based occlusion with python?

Tags: python, scripting, vertex-groups, procedural, vertex-weights

i was wondering if there's a way to bake (scene scale) ambient occlusion information into an object vertex group?

I believe the **only** option is to uv unwrap the terrain, create a new image texture, bake a cycle material into an image texture (a destructive i'd like to avoid),  then try to convert the uv image data into a vertex group. **but this solution is something i'd like to avoid.** as it's taking extremely destructive steps. is there a more direct solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bake to vertex colors in blender cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45964/how-to-bake-to-vertex-colors-in-blender-cycles)

Comment: brockmann no unfortunately i was searching for a more direct solution

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how the "_more direct solution_"  result would look ?

Comment: calculate a vertex based occlusion, a function that would receive point clouds as input and return normalized occlusion values ?